# C#: Unittesting with private static members?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, private-members

I have a class with a construct like this:

```
private static Dictionary<Contract, IPriceHistoryManager> _historyManagers = new Dictionary<Contract, IPriceHistoryManager>();
```

and lets say 2 methods like:

```
 public void AddSth()
 {
    _historManagers.Add(new Contract(), new PriceHistoryManager());
 }

 public int CountDic()
 {
    return _historyManagers.Count(); 
 }
```

**Problem:**
When running unittests there is no way to "reset" the Dictionary and when i create multiple unittests with seperate instances of the class, then "CountDic" gives unpredictable results and i can't test the listentries.

**Question:**
Is this generally considered a "bad" approach and if yes: how to do it better/more unittestable? 
And if not: How to unittest this best?

Thx.

Comment: why is the dictionary static?

Comment: Because it's used in a WCF-service and i want multiple instances of it to use it..

Comment: For what do you need a static dictionary?

Comment: You are using the static dictionary as a kind of cache?

Comment: @David could you not solve the issue of multiple instances using it by having a custom ServiceHostFactory which created the ServiceHost instances and injected a shared history manager, then you wouldn't need to compromise your design just for testing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't be afraid to expose public operations for testing purposes. Paraphrased from "The Art of Unit Testing" by Roy Osherove: When Toyota builds a car, there are testing points available. When Intel builds a chip, there are testing points available. There are interfaces to the car or chip that exist only for testing.  Why don't we do the same for software? Would a `ResetHistory()` method completely destroy your API?

If that answer is `yes`, then create the method, but make the method `internal`. You can then use the assembly `InternalsVisibleTo` to expose the guts to your unit test library. You have a  method available to you created 100% for testing, but there's no change to your public API.

Comment: Sometimes, yes; but here I'd rather break out a persistent class, makes for a cleaner design on the whole.

Comment: Another nice qoute from The Art of Unit Testing is "*When we write unit tests for our code, we are adding another end user (the test) to the object model. That end use is just as important as the original one, but it has different goals when using the model.*" (page 77) In other words, tests are an important user of your system and they justify making some parts of the application public (however, this might be different when writing a reusable class library of course).

Comment: I like the idea and will give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `CountDic` isn't unpredictable: it should return one more than before the call to `AddSth()`.

So:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var item = new ClassUnderTest();
    int initialCount = item.CountDic();

    item.AddSth();

    int finalCount = item.CountDic();

    Assert.That(finalCount == initialCount + 1);
}
```

In general, though, testing classes that maintain state can be tricky. Sometimes it's necessary to break out the part of the class that maintains state (in your case, the dictionary) and move it to another class. Then, you can mock that "storage" class and pass it in through a constructor.

Comment: if i have 3 independent unittests "in a row", each creating there own instance of the class and an unknown amount of "AddSth" calls then the 2nd and 3rd unittests have unpredictable amounts of entries in the list, as they don't and should'nt know of each other...

Comment: All you'll ever know (and all you can test) is the _change_ of the count -- this is the number of calls to AddSth().

Comment: Yes, but each test runs serially.  So you should know how many things you've added within a given test.

Comment: @David: if you create one instance per unittest the you need to rethink wether you really need the dictionary static.... And on each UnitTest you just get the CountDic() first before calling AddSth(). That way you get the initial value to test against...

Comment: Ok, if you have 3 Test() methods: Test1(), Test2(), Test3() you won't have predictable results anymore as they'are maybe executed by one instance of e.g. TestRunner.exe and the static list entries remain over the "testborders" and there is no way to reset them

Comment: @YvesM. In my WCF-service scenario i need multiple serviceinstances to calculate some stuff and then writing the results in the static list. Is this a bad approach after all? And why?

Comment: What are you doing with the results in the list after that? Just counting them? Or storing them later?

Comment: Off-Topic: but they should consider adding a chat ;-)